# Mac giving random flashes

Tags: mac, macos, hardware, screen, virus

I have a mid 2012 non-retina mac with El Captain. It is starting to get slower, especially due to the absence of the SSD, but it never gave me any problems.

It has been a couple of days now that seemingly at random, the screen flashes for just a moment. I mean that I can see the flash of the screen, usually white or blue, and then everything goes back to normal.

This happened 4 times already; what could be the cause? Should I be worried about a virus? Or maybe a hardware failure?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make sure you don't have 'Flash screen for Alerts' set in system prefs [search 'flash' top right]

Comment: @Tetsujin Maybe it's because my system is in Italian, but if I search for flash in the setting screen it only turns up Adobe Flash Player. Where should I navigate in the panel setting to go to the correct setting?

Comment: Ah... I hadn't thought about translations, sorry. Long path... System Prefs > Accessibility > Audio > & it's the top pref. There's also a test button so you can see for sure if it compares to what you're seeing.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks! Unfortunately the setting was not on, and the "flash test" it's way smoother than what I see, which is much faster with a higher intensity, and seems to affect mostly the upper part of the screen (though I can't be sure about that since it's too fast)

Comment: OK, might be hardware then - was worth a look anyway, just in case. I'd try running the hardware tests, see if anything comes up - https://support.apple.com/HT201257

Comment: @Tetsujin I ran the test (the short one) and there were no issues. Also the screen didn't blink while it was in the AHT screen, so I'm thinking maybe this could be a software problem? How to troubleshoot that now? :-)

Comment: Check to see if you're covered by this first - https://www.apple.com/uk/support/macbookpro-videoissues/ Software test would include 1) making a new clean admin account, 2) starting in safe mode or even 3) a total wipe & reinstall, depending on where in the software it is.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, I don't display any of those symptoms. So I guess I need to start a clean admin account and see if the problem recurs? If it doesn't, what  to do?

Comment: Try running some GPU intensive test like [Unigine Heaven](https://unigine.com/products/benchmarks/heaven/) and see if the artifacts appear.